# Why MSYS bash's PATH does not change when I have modified windows' PATH in environment variables

Tags: mingw, msysgit, msys

I am using Msys-git version 1.0 running under Windows 7. When I modify/add path in windows' environment variables, it is not reflected in Msys bash, why? It is reflected under windows cmd, however.

I can't find .profile or .bashrc file in my HOME directory. I wonder how those paths are set up when bash is run.